# Warning arise after conform `UIScrollViewDelegate`

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am facing a warning on the below line

[image]

This warning has arise after changing below line

```
@interface BDSAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

to

```
@interface BDSAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Here I just conform `UIScrollViewDelegate` and this warning arise. Every things work perfect but I can't understand how to remove this warning. Can any one explain why this coming and how to remove it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` returns a `id<UIApplicationDelegate>` which must be cast to `BDSAppDelegate` in order to prevent the warning.

In other words, all `BDSAppDelegate`'s are a `id<UIApplicationDelegate>` but that doesn't mean that all `id<UIApplicationDelegate>` are a `BDSAppDelegate`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` to the *public interface*, you should add
it to a *class extension* in the implementation file:

**BDSAppDelegate.h (public interface):**

```
...
@interface BDSAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> 
...
```

**BDSAppDelegate.m (implementation):**

```
#import "BDSAppDelegate.h"

@interface BDSAppDelegate () <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation BDSAppDelegate
...
@end
```

That makes the declaration *local* to the implementation, and

```
BSDAppDelegate *mainDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

works without a cast (and without warning).